# confuse about find - print and prune option (unix)

Tags: find

```
compa> find . -type d
.
./2015_08_30
./2015_08_25
./2015_08_27
./2015_08_31
./2015_08_24
./2015_08_26


compa> find . -type d -print
.
./2015_08_30
./2015_08_25
./2015_08_27
./2015_08_31
./2015_08_24
./2015_08_26
```

q1) I do not see any difference with or without the -print. Why do we use -print then ?

=================
Next I want to see the folder 2015_08_31 to be excluded.

```
compa> find . -name "2015_08_31"
./2015_08_31
compa> find . -name "2015_08_31" -prune
./2015_08_31
```

Only if I put a -o -print behind the prune, then it works

```
find . -name "2015_08_31" -prune -o -print
```

q2) Why ? What is actually -o ? I belive it is a "or" ?

Again adding a -o -name change everything again.

```
compa> find . -name "2015_08_31" -prune -o -name "2015_08_30"
./2015_08_30
./2015_08_31
```

q3) Why is it showing 08_30 and 08_31 when I have specify to prune "2015_08_31" ?

Answer (score 0):

The default action for `find` is print, which is why you don't see any difference with or without the print command in the initial example.

I have to admit that I've never used `-prune` but in reading the man page, it looks like it does not do what you seem to think it does.

> -prune True; if the file is a directory, do not descend into it.

This means that when a match is found, in this case on "2015_08_31", then `find` will not descend into the directory to continue finding files. Since the top level directory matches, and it `find` does not need to descend into it, then it will still take the action on it.

All of the subsequent examples seem to stem from this misunderstanding of what `-prune` does, or how `find` actually works.

If you want `find` to simply not print that directory, then try

```
find . -type d ! -name "2015_08_31"
```

In that command, `find` will print out the names of all of the directories under . except "2015_08_31". However, that command will print out any subdirectories under "2015_08_31".

If you want find to not show anything having to do with that directory, then you could try

```
find . -type d ! -regex "./2015_08_31.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

> q1) I do not see any difference with or without the -print. Why do we use -print then ?

`-print` is the default action of no other actions are specified. From the man page:

```
   If the expression contains no actions other than -prune, -print is per‐
   formed on all files for which the expression is true.
```

> q2) Why ? What is actually -o ? I belive it is a "or" ?

From the man page:

```
   expr1 -o expr2
          Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.
```

q3) Why is it showing 08_30 and 08_31 when I have specify to prune "2015_08_31" ?

The `-prune` action will stop `find` from descending into those directories, but will not exclude them from the output.  Consider the following file structure:

```
.
./2015_08_31
./2015_08_30
./2015_08_30/test_dir
./2015_08_30/test_dir/test_file_1
./2015_08_30/test_dir/test_file_3
./2015_08_30/test_dir/test_file_2
```

Running:

```
find . -name "2015_08_31" -prune -o -name "2015_08_30"
```

Will show:

```
./2015_08_31
./2015_08_30
```

That is, `find` does not descend into `prune`d directories.

Comment: there is an ambiguity in the -o then. Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.  if expr1 is true which is -name "2015_08_31", then why is 
expr2 "2015_08_30" shown ?